# Terminal without echo

Tags: console, terminal, echo, stty

In the terminal on Solaris 5.9 (ksh), I don't see the characters when typing. I can see the input only after the return key is pressed.
I checked terminal settings with `stty -a` it shows:

```
echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

meanwhile I have inspected `stty -a` on my linux box and it's the same:

```
echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

I know the `stty -echo` and `stty echo` can disable/enable echoing in the console.
It did on my linux, but didn't affect anything on the Solaris terminal where I'm suffering the issue.
So, what could it be?

Comment: Try rerouting your stdin back to dev/tty, as in this related question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994593/how-to-reroute-stdout-stderr-back-to-dev-tty